# How can I clear the terminal screen with Linux system calls in x86 assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, terminal, x86, nasm

Thank you for taking the time to review my question; however, be kind as I'm still a beginner x86 programmer.

I'll get straight to the point. I'm undertaking my first x86 project by attempting to create a Chess Engine (I know this is probably silly, but my reasoning is if I can actually pull this off then I can really improve my understanding of assembly language and add this project to my portfolio for future jobs).

My question is simply: how can I clear the terminal screen in an x86 program? I would need it to be done in a similar fashion to the bash command 'clear'.

You can go ahead and ignore most of my code, but pay attention to the bottom section.
If you look at the bottom of my code, there's a section with the label "Error_0x00000001". I would need to write some code that can clear the Linux terminal here, but I am having trouble.

This is the code I used to in an attempt to clear the screen according to ChatGPT:

```
section .data
    msg db "\033[2J", 0  ; Escape sequence to clear the screen followed by null terminator
    msg_len equ $ - msg  ; Calculate the length of the message

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Write the escape sequence to clear the screen
    mov eax, 4            ; Syscall number for write
    mov ebx, 1            ; File descriptor 1 (STDOUT)
    mov ecx, msg          ; Pointer to the message
    mov edx, msg_len      ; Length of the message
    int 0x80              ; Invoke the syscall
```

The code above that was generated by Chat GPT was fruitless, and it had no effect at all!

I did further research, and I came across this web-page:
https://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=2662.0

On this webpage, I came across some code that works, but only when it is used as a stand-alone program. The code suddenly does not work when I use it as a procedure for my chess engine. Here is the code that I am talking about from the web-page that I linked above:

```
; sysClear.asm
; Invokes command 'clear' to clear the gnu/linux console,
; (really it uses the bash command: echo -en "\033c")
; Compile: nasm -f elf sysClear.asm
; Link: ld -m elf_i386 sysClear.o -o sysClear
; Run: ./sysClear
;
; Author: Ferran Trapé
; Date: August 20, 2020

SECTION .data

; Structures

command        db   '//bin/echo', 0h ; command to execute as string
        arg1   db   '-en', 0h                    ; option -en in echo
        arg2   db  '\033c', 0h                ; ANSI escape code to clear
 
arguments      dd   command
        dd  arg1                            ; argument1 to pass to commandline
        dd  arg2                                   ; argument2
        dd  0h                                    ; end of structure

environment dd  0h                  ; No one arguments to pass as environment variables

SECTION .text
 global _start

_start:

; Function clear

 mov    eax, 11                     ; invoke SYS_EXECVE
 mov    ebx, command                ; address of the file to execute
 mov    ecx, arguments              ; address of the arguments to pass to the commandline
 mov    edx, environment            ; address of the environment variables
 int        80h
```

I find it so strange how the above code works and does clear the terminal, but only when it is within its own directory and treated as a single program. It is so frustrating that it doesn't clear the screen when I include this code as a procedure in an external file.

I know this is a long question, but what is going on? This was supposed to be such an easy part of my engine but I am getting quite angry at this.

If you can help and provide a solution, I would be most thankful. I appreciate any help and I want to move forward with this project as soon as possible. Thank you in advance. You can ask me any question if I am missing something. Thanks again.

Here is my actual code for the main file of my chess engine:

```
; Program Author: David Mark Serrano
; Program Name: Battle_Chess
; Date Created: July 12, 2023
; Version: 1.0
; Purpose: To render a textual chessboard on the Linux Terminal for a game of chess against an AI opponent

; Built using file "makefile":
;
; Battle_Chess: Board_Render.o Battle_Chess.o
;   ld -m elf_i386 -o Battle_Chess Battle_Chess.o Board_Render.o Print.o
;
; Print.o: Print.asm
;   nasm -f elf32 -g -o Print.o Print.asm
;
; Board_Render.o: Board_Render.asm
;   nasm -f elf32 -g -o Board_Render.o Board_Render.asm
;
; Battle_Chess.o: Battle_Chess.asm
;   nasm -f elf32 -g -o Battle_Chess.o Battle_Chess.asm

section .data ; Section for initialized data

; File Descriptors
STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1
STDERR equ 2

; String used in Chess Engine
Terminal_Length db "Columns: ", 0
Minimum_Columns db "150", 0
Terminal_Height db "Rows: ", 0
Minimum_Rows db "45", 0
Error_Message_0x00000001 db "Error 0x00000001: Required terminal dimensions aren't met. Ensure $COLUMNS = 150 and $LINES = 45.", 0xA, 0 

; Chess Pieces
whitePawns db 8
whiteRooks db 8
whiteKnights db 8
whiteBishops db 8
whiteQueen db 8
whiteKing db 8
blackPawns db 8
blackRooks db 8
blackKnights db 8
blackBishops db 8
blackQueen db 8
blackKing db 8

section .bss ; Section for uninitialized data
; No uninitialized data

section .text
    global _start

_start:

    nop ; This instruction is used to aid gdb debugger

    ; External references to global procedures defined in 'Print.asm'
    extern PrintString
    extern PrintRows
    extern PrintColumns

    ; External references to global procedural buffers defined in 'Print.asm'
    extern Columns
    extern Rows

    ; External references to global procedures defined in 'Board_Render.asm'
    extern GWINSZ

    ; External references to global procedural buffers defined in 'Board_Render.asm'
    extern terminal_clear

    ; This group of instructions (Line 53 - Line 76) set the initial positions of all game pieces on the Chessboard
    ; Each 8-byte variable is divided into high 32-bits and low 32-bits
    ; Each location in a variable where a bit is set directly corresponds to the game piece actively on that square
    mov dword [whitePawns], 0x0000FF00 ; The White Pawns are actively on { Files A - H; Rank 2  }
    mov dword [whitePawns + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Pawns actively on these squares
    mov dword [whiteRooks], 0x00000081 ; The white Rooks are actively on { File A; Rank 1 } and { File H - Rank 1 }
    mov dword [whiteRooks + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Rooks actively on these squares
    mov dword [whiteKnights], 0x00000042 ; White Knights are actively on { File B; Rank 1 } and { File G; Rank 1 }
    mov dword [whiteKnights + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Knights actively on these squares
    mov dword [whiteBishops], 0x00000024 ; White Bishops are actively on { File C; Rank 1 } { Rank F; File 1 }
    mov dword [whiteBishops + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Bishops actively on these squares
    mov dword [whiteQueen], 0x00000008 ; White Queen is actively on { File D; Rank 1 }
    mov dword [whiteQueen + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White Queen on these squares
    mov dword [whiteKing], 0x00000010 ; White King is actively on { File E; Rank 1 }
    mov dword [whiteKing + 4], 0x00000000 ; No White King on these squares
    mov dword [blackPawns], 0x00000000 ; No Black Pawns on these squares
    mov dword [blackPawns + 4], 0x00FF0000 ; Black Pawns are actively on { File A-H; Rank 7 }
    mov dword [blackRooks], 0x00000000 ; No Black Rooks on these squares
    mov dword [blackRooks + 4], 0x81000000 ; Black Rooks are actively on { File A; Rank 8 } { File H; Rank 8 }
    mov dword [blackKnights], 0x00000000 ; No Black Knights on these squares
    mov dword [blackKnights + 4], 0x42000000 ; Black Knights are actively on { File B; Rank 8 } { File G; Rank 8 }
    mov dword [blackBishops], 0x00000000 ; No black Bishops on these squares
    mov dword [blackBishops + 4], 0x24000000 ; Black Bishops are active on { File C; Rank 8 } { File F; Rank 8 }
    mov dword [blackQueen], 0x00000000 ; No Black Queen on these squares
    mov dword [blackQueen + 4], 0x08000000 ; Black Queen is actively on { File D; Rank 8 }
    mov dword [blackKing], 0x00000000 ; No Black King on these squares
    mov dword [blackKing + 4], 0x10000000 ; Black King is actively on { File E; Rank 8 }

    ; This instruction (Line XX) makes a call to procedure 'GWINSZ' in 'Board_Render.asm' file to retrieve dimensions of Linux Terminal
    call GWINSZ

    ; These instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will print the total $LINES of the current Linux Terminal session
    push Terminal_Length ; Push memory address of string 'Terminal_Length' onto stack
    push 0xA ; Push length of string "Terminal_Length' onto stack
    call PrintString ; Call procedure 'PrintString' from 'Print.asm' file
    call PrintColumns ; Call procedure 'PrintRows' from 'Print.asm' file

    ; These instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will ensure minimum Linux Terminal length is met, and if not met, the program will terminate
    xor eax, eax ; Clear 'eax' so that it is ready to store ASCII character in 'al'
    xor ecx, ecx ; Clear 'ecx' so that it is to be used as loop counter for 'CheckColumns' procedure
    xor edx, edx ; Clear 'edx' so that is is ready to store ASCII character in 'dl'
    CheckColumns:
    cmp ecx, 0x3 ; Check if 'ecx' has counted entire string "150"
    je CheckColumns.End
    mov al, BYTE [Columns + ecx] ; Copy contents of 'Columns' buffer in 'Print.asm' file to 'esi'
    mov dl, BYTE [Minimum_Columns + ecx] ; Copy contents of 'Minimum_Columns' in 'Battle_Chess.asm' buffer to 'edi'
    inc ecx ; Increase 'ecx' to update count for indexing into buffers 'Columns' and 'Minimum_Columns'
    cmp al, dl ; Compare ASCII character stored in 'al' with ASCII character stored in 'dl'
    jne Error_0x00000001 ; Jump to label 'Error_0x00000001' if 'al' and 'dl' are not equal
    je CheckColumns ; Repeat loop and jump to label 'Check_Columns' if 'al' and 'dl' are equal
    CheckColumns.End:

    ; These instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will print the total $COLUMNS of the current Linux Terminal session
    push Terminal_Height ; Push memory address of 'Terminal_Height' onto stack
    push 0x7 ; Push length of string 'Terminal_Height' onto stack 
    call PrintString ; Call procedure 'PrintString' from 'Print.asm' file
    call PrintRows ; Call procedure 'PrintColumns' from 'Print.asm' file

    ; These instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will ensure minimum Linux Terminal height is met, and if not met, the program will terminate
    xor eax, eax ; Clear 'eax' so that it is ready to store ASCII character in 'al'
    xor ecx, ecx ; Clear 'ecx' so that it is to be used as loop counter for 'CheckColumns' procedure
    xor edx, edx ; Clear 'edx' so that is is ready to store ASCII character in 'dl'
    CheckRows:
    cmp ecx, 0x2 ; Check if 'ecx' has counted entire string "45"
    je CheckRows.End
    mov al, BYTE [Rows + ecx] ; Copy contents of 'Columns' buffer in 'Print.asm' file to 'esi'
    mov dl, BYTE [Minimum_Rows + ecx] ; Copy contents of 'Minimum_Columns' in 'Battle_Chess.asm' buffer to 'edi'
    inc ecx ; Increase 'ecx' to update count for indexing into buffers 'Columns' and 'Minimum_Columns'
    cmp al, dl ; Compare ASCII character stored in 'al' with ASCII character stored in 'dl'
    jne Error_0x00000001 ; Jump to label 'Error_0x00000001' if 'al' and 'dl' are not equal
    je CheckRows ; Repeat loop and jump to label 'Check_Columns' if 'al' and 'dl' are equal
    CheckRows.End:

    nop ; This instruction is used to aid the GDB debugger

    ; This group of instructions (Line 97 - Line 97) will terminate the program and return code '0' to Linux to signal proper execution
    mov eax, 0x1 ; Specify sys_exit syscall
    xor ebx, ebx ; Clear `ebx` register so that it returns exit code 0
    int 0x80 ; Specify Vector Interrupt 128 (Kernel Services / Syscall Dispatcher)

    ; This group of instructions (Line XX - Line XX) will terminate the program and return code '1' to Linux to signal error
    Error_0x00000001:
    push Error_Message_0x00000001 ; Push memory address of 'Error_Message_0x00000001' onto stack
    push 0x63 ; Push length of 'Error_Message' onto stack (99 characters)
    call PrintString ; Print string 'Error_Message' to STDOUT
    mov eax, 0x1 ; Specify sys_exit syscall 
    mov ebx, 0x1 ; Set 'ebx' register to so that it returns exit code 1
    int 0x80 ; Specify Vector Interrupt 128 (Kernel Services / Syscall Dispatcher)
```

Comment: `db "\033[2J", 0` needs to be ```db `\033[2J`, 0```.  ChatGPT just copied C syntax into NASM because it has no idea what it's actually doing.  NASM only processes backslash \ escape sequences inside backticks.   (Actually, the `,0` is pointless, `write` takes a pointer+length, not a C string.)  Anyway, after that change, it works.

Comment: (I assembled that 32-bit code into a 32-bit executable, but you could equally well call `write` in 64-bit code with `syscall` and args in different registers; [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  But wait, your main program is 32-bit?  Why is this tagged [x86-64]?)

Comment: Also, yes, you could `execve` "/bin/echo", but that's an insane way to write a few bytes to stdout.  (You can pipe it into `hexdump -C` to see which bytes it wrote, though, to see what your asm needs to do).  And unless you `fork` first and only execve in the child process, it replaces your existing process.  But no, it doesn't run `bash`.  `echo` is a bash builtin, but there is a stand-alone `/bin/echo` binary executable that other programs could run.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter! Wow, that is quite a simple fix, but I probably would have never figured out the back tick without your help. Thank you very much and you got me back on track to programming my Chess Engine.